# How to copy/clone a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, copy, clone

I have a DataTable that will be modified by the user. I want to identify what's been change an keep record of that in the database.

The best way I see of doing this is by copying that DataTable before any changes are made and verify what's been changed when the user saves the form.

The problem is that wether I use myDataTable.Clone() or myDataTable.Copy(), the data are always the same. So I guess they just create references between the tables.

How would you handle this?

Comment: If you just want to keep track of differences, you may want to consider DataRowState - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the **[`DataSet.HasChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.haschanges.aspx)** method. This will tell you if there have been any changes to the dataset such as deleted or added rows, modified rows, etc.

You can also call **[`DataSet.GetChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getchanges.aspx)** to see what has changed. This method will return a copy of the changes.

For example, you could say:

```
private void VerifyChanges(DataSet dataSet)
{
    if(!dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified)) return;
    var changedDataSet = dataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);

    //... do the tracking or whatever else you want here.        
}
```

Or if you don't want to get all the DataSet changes, and just want the changes *from a specific table*:

```
private void VerifyChanges(DataSet dataSet, string tableName)
{
    if(!dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified)) return;
    var changedTable = dataSet
        .Tables[tableName]
        .GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);

    //... do the tracking or whatever else you want here.        
}
```

Lastly, to pull the original values out of the modified DataSet you could code:

```
row[columnIndex, DataRowVersion.Original]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tested and yes, it returns the modified rows. Although it doesn't give me the original value!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the quick and dirty way would be to `serialize` then `deserialize` the DataTable. If you decide to use xml serialization, be sure to nest the DataTable within a DataSet first.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use of [DataTable.GetChanges Method (DataRowState)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8.aspx).
This method returns a new data table with the rows that were changed.

Example:

```
DataTable changeTable = table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

Having this table you can compare the rows one-by-one with another DataTable.

Comment: Thanks. It returns the modified rows. Although it doesn't give me the original value!